# How does this class repaint automatically after the mouse is pressed?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I just don't see how the `paint()` or `paintComponent()` is being called here. This is from an old youtube video back in 2011; the comment section of that video didn't help. I was expecting this code to call `repaint()` in the `mousePressed()` method, but it didn't, and it just works.

This is the youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PrPwCKr6WNI

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class JavaApplication17 extends JFrame {

  int GWIDTH = 800;
  int GHEIGHT = 600;
  int x, y;
  private Image dbImage;
  private Graphics dbg;

  public JavaApplication17() {
    setSize(GWIDTH, GHEIGHT);
    setTitle("Game");
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    addMouseListener(new Mouse());
    x = 15;
    y = 15;
  }

  public class Mouse extends MouseAdapter {

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
      int xCoord = e.getX();
      int yCoord = e.getY();
      x = xCoord + 7;
      y = yCoord + 7;
    }
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
    dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
    paintComponent(dbg);
    g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.fillOval(x, y, 15, 15);
    repaint();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JavaApplication17 main = new JavaApplication17();
  }

}
```

Comment: post a link to the YouTube video

Comment: This is the video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PrPwCKr6WNI

Answer (score 1):

> how the `paint()` or `paintComponent()` is being called here?

`paintComponent()` is called by your code in `paint()` method.

`paint()` method is called by Swing framework every time when frame update is needed. By invoking `repaint()` method you're informing the Swing framework that your frame needs to update its content.

In IntelliJ IDEA this code looks like:

[image: paint method screenshot]

Note the letter `O` in blue circle. It means that the method `paint()` overrides some method in a parent class. In Java, it's recommended to add `@Override` modifier to mark overridden methods.

Your class `JavaApplication17` extends class `JFrame` which means it inherits all methods of `JFrame` and its ancestors. `JFrame` class in its turn extends `Frame` and inherits all methods of `Frame` and its ancestors. And so on. See the class hierarchy diagram:

[image: Swing classes hierarchy]

`Window` and `Container` classes both implement their `public void paint(Graphics g)` methods. And in the abstract `Component` class `paint()` is called by `update()` method. You don't need to call the `paint()` method on your own.

If you want to learn more and understand how it works, read about OOP concepts in Java (abstraction, encapsulation, inheritance, and polymorphism).

Comment: But how does it know that frame update is needed, or what caused the `update()` method to run?
Also, what is the class of `update()`?

Comment: @Noob
1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341618/swing-refresh-cycle
2. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html
3. "Java Swing" book, page 1013, "Swing painting delegation" chart.

Comment: JComponent extends Container, Container extends Component.
`JComponent.update(Graphics)` ->  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#update(java.awt.Graphics)
`Container.update(Graphics)` -> 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#update(java.awt.Graphics)
`Component.update(Graphics)` -> 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#update(java.awt.Graphics)

Comment: I read the links, but it would be really nice if you actually give a step by step summary of what causes `update()` to be called, so I can mark this question as answered. I know those links are probably good enough for the average java programmer, and I kind of get the gist of it, but I still can't get the full picture in my head.